# Very slow to access iProperties with Inventor iLogic 2023.3

Tags: autodesk-inventor

We just updated from Inventor 2021 to 2023 and I've noticed that accessing `iProperties` with iLogic and add-ins is extremely slow only when logged into Vault(2023.2.1 server), about a second to per property to read or write to it via `iProperties.Value(...)` or `Doc.PropertySets("...")("...").Value`.

It is only slow when logged into Vault within Inventor, if I am logged out it only takes a second to go through 20+ properties.

I am particularly getting properties from the referenced model of an active drawing, but it is still slow when I try to access the drawing `iProperties` from the active drawing.

Anyone ever have this happen/have any suggestions?